# Asynchronous UART transfer in microcontroller 8051

Tags: serial-port, microcontroller, 8051, microprocessors

Hi i am trying to communicate my 89c52 with sim548c module. I am sending AT commands and then making the microcontroller store all replies in an array and go through a search function to see if proper reply was sent so it can move on to next AT command. This requires two way serial transfer. i have to first send serially the AT command, then enable reception and store all replies from the module in an array. I am using this program but i cant get the microcontroller to accept the incoming data and store it in an array. it transfers successfully but doesnt receive. Can you kindly identify what is the problem?

```
int check=0;
int out=0;
unsigned char info[20]={"00000000000000000000"};
unsigned char  *s;
unsigned char a[3],b[3];

void transmit_data(unsigned char str)        
{
    SBUF=str;                                  
    while(TI==0);
    TI=0;                          
}

void send_serial(unsigned char *s)
{
    delay(50);
    while(*s!=0x0)
    {
        SBUF=*s;
        while(TI==0)
        {
        }
    TI=0;
    s++;
    }
}

void receive_data()            interrupt 4                      
{
    if(RI)
    {
        info[check++]=SBUF;
        RI=0;
    }
    if(TI)
        TI=0;
}

void search(unsigned char b[])
{
    int l=0;
    for(l;l<18;l++)
    {
        if(info[l]==b[0] && info[l+1]==b[1] && info[l+2]==b[2])
        {
            out=1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void compare(unsigned char *s, unsigned char a[]) //for CIPSEND
{
    while(1)
    {
        out=0;
        check=0;
        delay(50);
        send_serial("AT+CIPSEND\r");
        delay(100);
        send_serial(s);
        transmit_data(0x0D);
        transmit_data(0x0A);
        transmit_data(0x1A);
        IE=0x90;
        delay(200);
        IE=0x88;
        search(a);  
        if (out==1)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are RI and SBUF defined? Are they flagged as volatile when necessary? And can you do a loopback or generate known data and see if your receive is working at all?

Comment: I think you should mention the compiler/libs used.

Answer (score 1):

i have seen this a couple of times and th mistake is that your serial receive works with an interrupt and it is not a voidable function smply remove the VOID that is attached to INTERRUPT 4 so tha ur code becomes

```
 receive_data()            interrupt 4                      
{
    if(RI)
    {
        info[check++]=SBUF;
        RI=0;
    }
    if(TI)
        TI=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a smaller (as simple as you can) program that does nothing more than receive (by interrupt?) data and blink a LED or echo it back or in some other way indicate that you can reliably receive. Use that to talk to a terminal emulator or another known working interface. Cut out all possible middlemen and unknowns.

Check also UART error registers and configuration to make sure your clock/parity/data settings match in both ends. Start with a slow rate first.

Make one piece at a time work reliably, then put them together.